# Pythonic way to avoid infinte loop in mutually connected QObjects

Tags: python, pyqt4

Let's say I have two QspinBoxes and if I update spinBox_1 the second will show twice this value. If I update spinBox_2 the first one will show half this value. Using two methods like `on_valueChanged1` and `on_valueChanged2` and mutual connection with `SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)")` works fine here. Change in 1 calls the method to change 2, which then changes and calls 1 again. Fortunately the thing stops here, as the choice of factor 2 and 1/2 works out, so the second value actually does not change. If choosing other values, this results in a virtually infinite call and recall.

What would be the Pythonic way to solve this. Would I `disconnect` the `SIGNAL` and `connect` again after the changes, or is there a solution too obvious for me to see?

**Update**
A snipped of a working example with `hasFocus()` looks like:

```
QMainWindow.connect(self.ui.doubleSpinBox,SIGNAL("valueChanged(double)"),self.on_change1)
QMainWindow.connect(self.ui.doubleSpinBox_2,SIGNAL("valueChanged(double)"),self.on_change2)

def on_change1(self):
    if self.ui.doubleSpinBox.hasFocus():
        self.ui.doubleSpinBox_2.setValue(3.3*self.ui.doubleSpinBox.value())

def on_change2(self):
    if self.ui.doubleSpinBox_2.hasFocus():
        self.ui.doubleSpinBox.setValue(self.ui.doubleSpinBox_2.value()*.77)
```

So apart from the fact that it is working, is this the best/most general solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you split on_valueChanged to only detect manual (and not signaled) changes on the objects?

That way if you alter spinBox_1, its on_valueChanged1 callback signals spinBox_2 to change, but doesn't trigger the on_valueChanged2, avoiding the inifinite loop.

Comment: Interesting point. Can you do that? How would you do that? Would I use `hasFocus()`? Also `setUpdatesEnabled()` might be an option.

Comment: `hasFocus()` might be a safe bet, since only the field the user is tweaking has the focus. `setUpdatesEnabled()` only affects drawing and updating, so it might not stop the callback from being called.

Comment: That was my impression looking at the class reference "disable updates for a short period of time, for instance to avoid screen flicker"; so `hasFocus()` will result in an extra if-statement.